# Grails run-app exits without starting server after version upgrade

Tags: grails

I've just upgraded my grails app from version 1.1.1 to version 1.3.7, and now when I run the 'run-app' target it simply pushes some files around and then exits without error, instead of launching the application server. I've cleaned and recompiled everything, but nothing seems to make it work. The output from run-app is as follows:

```
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: C:\SDKs\grails-1.3.7

Base Directory: C:\Users\User\Documents\IntelliJ\MediaServices\LectureRecordingControl\LectureRecordingControl
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 689ms.
Running script C:\SDKs\grails-1.3.7\scripts\RunApp.groovy
Environment set to development
    [copy] Copying 1 resource to C:\Users\User\Documents\IntelliJ\MediaServices\LectureRecordingControl\LectureRecordingControl
    [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\User\Documents\IntelliJ\MediaServices\LectureRecordingControl\LectureRecordingControl\grails-shared-files.jar into C:\Users\User\Documents\IntelliJ\MediaServices\LectureRecordingControl\LectureRecordingControl
    [delete] Deleting: C:\Users\User\Documents\IntelliJ\MediaServices\LectureRecordingControl\LectureRecordingControl\grails-shared-files.jar
    [copy] Copying 1 resource to C:\Users\User\Documents\IntelliJ\MediaServices\LectureRecordingControl\LectureRecordingControl
    [unjar] Expanding: C:\Users\User\Documents\IntelliJ\MediaServices\LectureRecordingControl\LectureRecordingControl\grails-app-files.jar into C:\Users\User\Documents\IntelliJ\MediaServices\LectureRecordingControl\LectureRecordingControl
    [delete] Deleting: C:\Users\User\Documents\IntelliJ\MediaServices\LectureRecordingControl\LectureRecordingControl\grails-app-files.jar
```

At this point the script terminates with exit code 0, as if this is exactly what was meant to happen.

During compile there were a few deprecation warnings, but nothing that looked as if it should have caused a failure. I don't think this is a plugin related issue, but just in case, the plugins active in this project are:

- feeds-1.5
- filterpane-0.7
- hibernate-1.1.1
- ldap-0.8.2
- mail-0.7.1
- modalbox-0.3
- navigation-1.0.4
- quartz-0.4.1
- richui-0.6

Does anyone have any idea what might have caused this issue? I can't find any information about upgrading from 1.1.1 directly to 1.3.7, perhaps I should have moved to some intermediate version first?

Comment: Maybe try adding the `--verboseCompile` argument to your run-app command. Other advice in this thread might help you too: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Verbose-output-on-the-grails-run-app-possible-td2271847.html ?